# Printing multiple files with different print options using libcups

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I am using libcups on Linux to print files. I want to print multiple files in one print request with different cups_options_t for each file. There is a library API cupsPrintFiles  but as per its interface it applies one cups_options_t to every file. Is there any solution to this in the CUPS API. If there is no support in CUPS API the only other option I am left with to use a queue for all files since I want to keep order and use cupsPrintFile. Thoughts.

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.

Comment: I am interested in the answer as well... How do you create a queue ?

Comment: I am using C++ std::queue with some locking to make it thread safe. For C you can find some quick implementations on google.

Comment: Oh then you are still printing the files individually once the preprocessing is over... with different jobIds ? What I need is a single jobId for the case of multiple users sending concurrent jobs to the same printer... I will try to implement this by trying to write a printToFile backend.